# How to generate @HandlerChain using wsimport

Tags: java, jax-ws, wsimport, handlers

I'm generating Java from WSDL using wsimport (JAX-WS 2.1.3) and need to make it generate a @HandlerChain annotation. So I create a JAX-WS binding file:

```
<jaxws:bindings
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
wsdlLocation="../etc/MessageStudio.wsdl">

<jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions">
    <javaee:handler-chain>
        <javaee:handler-chain-name>StrongmailHandlers</javaee:handler-chain-name>               
            <javaee:handler>
                <javaee:handler-name>OrganizationTokenHandler</javaee:handler-name>         
                <javaee:handler-class>com.bossmedia.strongmailadapter.deliveryadapter.OrganizationTokenHandler</javaee:handler-class>           
            </javaee:handler>                     
    </javaee:handler-chain>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

and run the wsimport Ant task:

```
 <wsimport 
        wsdl="../etc/MessageStudio.wsdl"
        sourcedestdir="../src/gen"
        destdir="../classes"
        verbose="false"
        binding="../etc/jaxws.bindings.xml">
 </wsimport>
```

but I get no annotation and no handler chain XML file. Googling only finds me solutions for changing packages, methods and arguments and [the JAX-WS RI page](http://jax-ws.java.net/nonav/2.1.3/docs/customizations.html#2.10_Handler_chain_customization) from where I copied the XML.

Could you help me find the flaw in my configuration or another way, short of modifying the generated code, to get my handler into the chain?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The answer is that the RI example is **incorrect**. There needs to be a handler-chains wrapper tag:

```
<jaxws:bindings
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
wsdlLocation="../etc/MessageStudio.wsdl">

<jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions">
    <javaee:handler-chains>
        <javaee:handler-chain>
            <javaee:handler-chain-name>StrongmailHandlers</javaee:handler-chain-name>               
            <javaee:handler>
                <javaee:handler-name>OrganizationTokenHandler</javaee:handler-name>         
                <javaee:handler-class>com.bossmedia.strongmailadapter.deliveryadapter.OrganizationTokenHandler</javaee:handler-class>           
            </javaee:handler>                     
        </javaee:handler-chain>
    </javaee:handler-chains>
</jaxws:bindings>
```

Comment: Another poor b*stard misled by the documentation. Now it works. Thanks

Comment: Many thanks!!! That mistake in the example took 2 hours of research and debugging etc... until I found this helpful hint. It works now! and check the second commend regarding the handler-file.xml where it is put ... strange behaviour!

Answer (score 2):

It turns out that the generated handler chain file is put in the output directory (target/package) where the compiled class files are. If you want to change that, you can use the "destDir" option to do that. Also, set "xnocompile" to false else the generated class files will end up in the same directory as the handler file. Wish they didn't do such a half a**ed job at documentation.

Answer (score 1):

There is still an error in the example. The tag `<javaee:handler-chain-name>` does not exist according to the XML scheme (http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/jsc/xml/ns/javaee/javaee_web_services_metadata_handler_2_0.xsd).

The correction is:

```
<jaxws:bindings
xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
xmlns:jaxb="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
xmlns:jaxws="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxws"
xmlns:javaee="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
wsdlLocation="../etc/MessageStudio.wsdl">

<jaxws:bindings node="wsdl:definitions">
    <javaee:handler-chains>
        <javaee:handler-chain>
            <javaee:handler>
                <javaee:handler-name>OrganizationTokenHandler</javaee:handler-name>         
                <javaee:handler-class>com.bossmedia.strongmailadapter.deliveryadapter.OrganizationTokenHandler</javaee:handler-class>           
            </javaee:handler>                     
        </javaee:handler-chain>
    </javaee:handler-chains>
```

Comment: there seem to still be two missing end tags </jaxws:bindings>